# Problem with Repository build.gradle statement Could not GET, Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized

Tags: maven, android-studio, kotlin, repository, build.gradle

I want to use my project in [this](https://github.com/tsili852/app-theme-engine) library but encountered an error in the build.gradle phase
I tried searching a lot on Google and did not find an answer that solved the problem
I get an error that the server did not approve access
I'm a bit new in the field and from the answers of others on this issue and from reading gradle's official documentation, I realized I needed to add a username and password but did not understand what username I should use or should be set as default as I wrote in the code below
Thanks for all the help!

That's my code right now

```
    repositories {
        google ()
        jcenter ()
        maven {
            credentials {
                username "user"  
                password "password"
            }
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }
```

And this is the error that is accepted

Unable to resolve dependency for ': app @ releaseUnitTest / compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.github.afollestad: app-theme-engine: 0.2.1.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsRelease'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:releaseCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.github.afollestad:app-theme-engine:0.2.1.
> Required by:
> project :app
> > Could not resolve com.github.afollestad:app-theme-engine:0.2.1.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jitpack.io/com/github/afollestad/app-theme-engine/0.2.1/app-theme-engine-0.2.1.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jitpack.io/com/github/afollestad/app-theme-engine/0.2.1/app-theme-engine-0.2.1.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized

Sorry for my weak English ..
Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Can you post also your module `build.gradle` file?

Comment: implementation('com.github.afollestad:app-theme-engine:0.2.1') {
        transitive = true}
This is what I added for this library

Comment: Need the whole file? I do not mind posting it here if there is a simple need is long so I wanted to summarize